# Always use "lowest possible value" for SQLite primary key?

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a table, PERSON_TABLE, which has, P_ID, P_NAME, P_AGE

P_ID is primary key and autoincrement..

i have an activity that the user will manually put data to each columns .
If success, it will have a primary key, starting from 1, then 2 , then 3 and so on.

but the application also has its delete function. 
If I delete row 2, then i insert again 1 row, it will have primary key 4, i would like that the next inserted data will use the first available primary key, which is 2. How can i achieve that?

thanks

Comment: i think in this case, you should not set autoincrement for your primary key, then you have to think up a algorithm to find what is value for primary key every time you insert data

Comment: Have you tried this?   http://sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_last_insert_rowid

Comment: is that the only way? i thought about that but i would really like to use the correct way if it has one. thanks anyway...still waiting for other answers.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 - honestly, i dont quite understand it that well. but i feel it isnt the way. can you explain it to me?

Comment: Step back and ask yourself _why_ you think you need this.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 That won't work for this task. The primary purpose of that function is to get the rowid of the previous insert. (It has nothing to do with the selection of a new key or generation of a "packed" primary key.)

Comment: @paxdiablo - i really need this primary key to be organized but not reassigned.. my application kinda is database-heavy and there will be complication if i dont use the PK. My application above is not the real one, just a sample

Comment: @paxdiablo Lol, it was. The +1 for you.

Comment: @mcr619619 If that's the reason you're giving .. ;( Most database design rely on the use of Keys (PK and otherwise). Trying to always get the "lowest possible free value as a PK" is an unrelated task to performance. It won't save space or make the database smaller (and, in fact, it will decrease performance and increase fragmentation without a justifiable positive effect!)

Comment: @mcr619619, I see no problems with having the primary key itself. What I'm asking you to question is your need to have them contiguous. There will _always_ be a time when they're not contiguous (immediately following a delete) meaning your app will need to deal with it, so why would it be a requirement to try and avoid that at all.

Comment: @pst and pax  - i know it wont save space but i really need to have that PK to be contiguous. It will be very long story if i explain all. I never knew it would increase fragmentation. I dont think there's a way so I'm going to use algorithm as MichaelP said. thanks to all.

Comment: Well, I would rather take the time to understand the reason, however long it may be :-) Just saying you need it contiguous without explaining severely reduces the solutions that can be given. That's rarely a good approach to take when trying to solve a problem. That's your call of course, I'm just saying that, in my _long_ history, you start out allowing _any_ solution and then whittle it down from there. Starting with a (possibly unnecessary) reduced solution set disregards a lot of potential avenues. In any case, my whole family's nicked off to the tennis so I have some time to play :-)

Answer (score 3):

You really should re-examine this requirement - it is rarely necessary.

Since there will always be a situation where there are gaps in your sequences (unless you resequence on delete, which *will* be a performance killer), your app will have to deal with it.

And, since your app deals with it, it may as well deal with it all the time.

I can think of no real reason why an artificial primary key would need to be contiguous. Gaps in the sequencing won't affect performance other than for poorly written queries which use the primary key as real data (and they probably shouldn't be doing that with an artificial key).

So my advice is to *start* with the assumption that contiguous keys are *not* needed (as opposed to starting with the thought that they're required), then come up with a reason why you think they are. I think you'll find it hard to come up with a reason that can't be satisfied in a better way.